# How to make child ImageView take the shape appearance of the parent MaterialCardView?

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview, material-components-android, material-components

I have a `MaterialCardView` which has the following shape appearance:
[image]

I want to put an `ImageView` in there which takes the exact shape appearance of the `MaterialCardView`.

Following is the stuff I have tried:

MaterialCardView Setting:

```
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
android:clipChildren="true"
```

> I think the above setting works only with original card view for card corner radius

I know that you can create a shape xml or CustomImageView to achieve it.

But I just want to know if there is a direct way to clip all the childrens.

**Note**: I am using `MaterialCardView` from Material library not the regular `CardView`

Comment: I do this all the time, it should work right out of the box, there is something else going on, share the xml

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `ShapeableImageView` and apply the same corners.
Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/roundedImageView16"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        ..>

        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:padding="8dp"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/roundedImageView16"
        ../>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

with:

```
  <style name="roundedImageView16">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">16dp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

**Note**: it requires at least the version **`1.2.0-alpha03`**.

Comment: Oh so they did came up with one, when I posted it I created one of my own after founding no solution. https://github.com/ndhabrde11/ShapeImageView

Answer (score 0):

If using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) you can do it like this:

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions = requestOptions.transforms(new CenterCrop(), new RoundedCorners(16));
Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
        .load([Image Location])
        .apply(requestOptions)
        .into([Your ImageView]);
```

you have to set ImageView properties like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ... />
```

Comment: But this would add rounded corners to all four corners. I you look at the MaterialCardView It has only two rounded corners